# Import "decouple" could not be resolved in Python

Tags: python, import, pip, python-decouple

So I'm trying to import config from the ".env" file via python-decouple but when I try do the import:

```py
from decouple import config
```

it returns the error of:

```
Import "decouple" could not be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your python module named decouple.py by any chance? wondering if it is a naming conflict if you are sure you have installed decouple successfully

Comment: There seems to be a file named decouple.py in my env/Lib/site-packages folder but there is only one. There is also a folder by the name of decouple if it is by any help.